# How do i replace all occurences of a substring with another substring in a string?

Tags: node.js

I tried

```
str = "sampletext11111111"
str.replace("1","a")
console.log(str)
```

The result it gives is

```
sampletexta1111111
```

please help

Comment: have a look at replaceAll https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: Im using node.js, not js

Comment: NodeJS _is_ JavaScript. There are a few implementation differences between JavaScript in NodeJS and JavaScript in a browser, but for the vast majority of non-DOM cases, the syntax and library are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply a regex and use the `g`lobal modifier:

```js
let str = "sampletext11111111"
str = str.replace(/1/g,"a")
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `replaceAll`:

```js
let str = "sampletext11111111"
str = str.replaceAll("1", "a")
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Im using node.js, i have attempted using .replaceAll, but it tells me it is not a function

Comment: @Radiant It's important to include what version of node you are using because the version determines what newer features of JavaScript are available to you. For instance, the `replaceAll` function is an ES2021 feature which was added in NodeJS 15, and if you are using an older version than 15, the function will not exist. If possible, I'd recommend using the latest stable version of NodeJS (which is 15.0.1 at time of writing). If you prefer using the latest LTS version (14.15.0) or are stuck using an older version for other reasons, you will need to use eol's solution.